# PostgreSQL not using index-only scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm using Postgres 12. I have a sales_history table with 999900 rows. Columns in the table include:

```
order_id numeric NOT NULL,
product_id numeric NOT NULL,
customer_id numeric NOT NULL,
sales_person_id numeric,
quantity numeric NOT NULL,
unit_price numeric,
sale_amount numeric,
sales_date date,
total_amount numeric,
CONSTRAINT sales_history_pkey PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
```

My sample data:
[image]

I have this query:

```
select sales_date
from sales_history
where (quantity * unit_price) between 5000000 and 10000000
```

I create an index for the (quantity * unit_price) and column sales_date, and I expect the query to use index-only scan

```
create index idx_sale_diff on sales_history( (quantity * unit_price), sales_date )
```

However, the query use bitmap scan instead:
[image]

I tried to VACUUM and ANALYZE but it's still bitmap scan

Can someone explain why this query did not use the index-only scan ? As I understand, all the columns needed for the query are available in the index so there's no need to do the bitmap scan

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are not enough blocks marked “all visible” in the *visibility map* of the table, so that PostgreSQL has to visit the table in many cases to determine if the row is visible or not.

The solution is

```
VACUUM sales_history;
```

which will update the visibility map.

You have to `VACUUM` a table regularly to get index only scans. With `INSERT`-only tables, that does not happen automatically in PostgreSQL versions below v13.